# Access object variable from service in my activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service, android-dialogfragment

What is the best way to access an object (in this case a BluetoothGatt object, but could be any variable) in a service that started in MainActivity.java from a new activity, from which I have bound to the service?

I've opened a new activity (SensorDataDisplay.java) from within a DialogFragment called from MainActivity.java. I then used bindService to bind to the already running BluetoothLeService.java.

I need to be able to access a BluetoothGatt object from my service in the new activity.

Comment: use "bound local service" pattern then

Comment: @pskink can you please send me a link where I can find documentation on this?

Comment: sure: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Binder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways you can communicate between Activity and Service.

1. [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services). As you can't have 2 Activity visible state at a time so you can bind only one Activity to Service at a time.
2. [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Event Bus will help you to communicate between Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc.
3. [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager). LocalBroadcastManager send broadcasts to your application components.

You can use any one them that suits with your requirements.